# How to sharpen/complete/correct text in image

Tags: c#, image

I have some scanned images that contain text.  After scanning, the text is dull and in some places the text is missing some pixels. The pixel loss is really small but enough that sharpening the image is not enough.  I would like to find an algorithm that will sharpen the text and attempt to complete or correct the pixels that have been lost during scanning.  I know this is a tall order but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I am using C#.  I know how to sharpen an image but not specifically for text.  I am open to other languages if there are advantages.  I have looked into Imagemagick and found some scripts to help despeckle and clean text.  I really need a "repair" more than anything.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Might not be what you're looking for, but we use Pegasus Imaging products, and their [ScanFix module](http://www.accusoft.com/scanfixfeatures.htm) can do this sort of thing.

Specifically, check out the smoothing features and character enhancement.  It might be overkill for what you need, but I really like their stuff.  Might be worth grabbing a trial version and giving it a run.